# Average of aggregations on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to compute the *average* value of all defined aggregations in a single ES query. The query results are used to populate [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKaaM.png).

First column ("*Lead time*") are buckets while the remaining five are metrics on those buckets. The catch is I also need the average value of each metric calculated on the buckets as shown in row five.

Here is the relevant part of the ES query I've written so far:

```
  "aggs": {
    "by_lead_time": {
      "range": {
        "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkIn'].value) - new Date(doc['timestamp'].value); return duration.days; }",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 1,
            "key": "Same day"
          },
          {
            "from": 1,
            "to": 7,
            "key": "Same week"
          },
          {
            "from": 7,
            "to": 14,
            "key": "Next week"
          },
          {
            "from": 14,
            "to": 31,
            "key": "Same month"
          },
          {
            "from": 31,
            "to": 93,
            "key": "Within 3 months"
          },
          {
            "from": 93,
            "key": "Longer than 3 months"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "averageDailyRate": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkOut'].value) - new Date(doc['checkIn'].value); return doc['totalPreTax'].value / duration.days; }"
          }
        },
        "averageLeadTime": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkIn'].value) - new Date(doc['timestamp'].value); return duration.days; }"
          }
        },
        "bookingCount": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "uuid"
          }
        },
        "roomNights": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkOut'].value) - new Date(doc['checkIn'].value); return duration.days; };"
          }
        },
        "averageLengthOfStay": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkOut'].value) - new Date(doc['checkIn'].value); return duration.days; }"
          }
        },
        "totalRevenue": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "totalPreTax"
          }
        },
        "lowestDailyRate": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nights"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_rate": {
              "min": {
                "field": "nights.rate.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "highestDailyRate": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nights"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_rate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "nights.rate.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "averageOccupants": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "return doc['noOfAdults'].value + doc['noOfChildren'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This works as expected for extracting the needed values, except overall averages. The thing is I have no clue on how to perform an `"avg"` over bucket values *after* they have been calculated, apart from manual labor on the client app. It should be clear from looking at the table picture, but bare in mind that this is **not** an average *on each bucket*, but the average of all the values for each metric.

How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using ES 2.0 or a previous release?

Comment: I am using 1.7. But I _could_ use 2.0 if there's a real benefit from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in ES 2.0 using [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html), more specifically [average bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html).

I have tested your scenario only with `roomNights` and `averageDailyRate` averages. The query in 2.0 would look like this, the other numerical aggregations should be done in a similar way:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_lead_time": {
      "range": {
        "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkIn'].value) - new Date(doc['timestamp'].value); return duration.days; }",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 1,
            "key": "Same day"
          },
          {
            "from": 1,
            "to": 7,
            "key": "Same week"
          },
          {
            "from": 7,
            "to": 14,
            "key": "Next week"
          },
          {
            "from": 14,
            "to": 31,
            "key": "Same month"
          },
          {
            "from": 31,
            "to": 93,
            "key": "Within 3 months"
          },
          {
            "from": 93,
            "key": "Longer than 3 months"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "roomNights": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkOut'].value) - new Date(doc['checkIn'].value); return duration.days; };"
          }
        },
        "averageDailyRate": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def duration = new Date(doc['checkOut'].value) - new Date(doc['checkIn'].value); return doc['totalPreTax'].value / duration.days; }"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_roomNights": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_lead_time>roomNights"
      }
    },
    "avg_averageDailyRate": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_lead_time>averageDailyRate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Also, you need to be aware of this bug - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14273 - in 2.0 which will make your scripts unusable.** I tested the query I provided with a 2.0.1 snapshot version built locally. If you're interested in testing this in 2.x, [these](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/2.0#building-from-source) are the instructions on how to build a version straight from github.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, Andrei Stefan because you gave a working solution. Any idea on how to approach this on earlier ES versions?

Comment: I don't think so, @NicolásFantone. Pipeline aggregations is one of the main themes in ES 2.0 and it was a long time feature request for ES.